# MIPS : Reinitialize an array inside " .text "

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

Can i reinitialize the array in the ".text" part in any way ??

like that

```
.data
array1: .word 0:12

.text
array1: .word 2:12
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: If `.text` means the code part of the program, it is up to your OS to decide if is writable or not. Nowadays mostly not.

Comment: Why aren't you simply use `mov`?